# Scala xml : dependency between attributes

Tags: scala

Our application receives an XML message from another system. The XML is structured like this:

```
<params>
  <param name="FOO" value="BAR"/>
  ...
</params>
```

What is the best way, using Scala's native XML processing, to return the value `BAR` for the parameter which is `FOO`, so that:

```
val foo = "BAR"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your xml is invalid with missing `param` closing tag, it should be, for example

```
var x = <params>
  <param name="FOO" value="BAR" />
  <param name="FOO2" value="BAR2" />
</params>
```

If you want to extract the only param `FOO`, I don't think you will find anything much better than

```
(x \ "param" find (n => (n \ "@name").toString == "FOO")).get \ "@value"
```

If you want to get all params, you can iterate over them:

```
x \ "param" foreach {n => println(n \ "@name" + " -> " + n \ "@value")}
```